# Remove missing drive from Spotlight

Tags: spotlight

I was cloning someone's drive, it was named *Macintosh HD*, just like my my own. Eventually it showed up in Spotlight as ***Macintosh HD 1***.

[image: Spotlight showing missing disconnected external drive]

Now when I search for apps and such I always hit its applications. At least nothing happens, since the drive has been removed and no longer exists.

How can I get Spotlight to stop showing me results for it?

I've tried reindexing with the following commands but it only applies to mounted devices:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

Comment: @user3439894 Cool, I didn't know you could skip spelling full paths like that. I'll try it out! Thanks

Comment: @user3439894 This worked! Would mind making an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turning `off|on` **Spotlight** *indexing* using `sudo mdutil -i off|on`, doesn't mean the *metadata stores* are cleaned up and or rebuilt. Here's what I'd do...

First delete the **Spotlight** *metadata stores* using `sudo mdutil -E /` and wait for the prompt to return. What actually happens is *indexing* is temporarily turned off, the *metadata stores* are deleted and *indexing* turned back on.

Then run `sudo -k` to terminate the `sudo` session.

Next I'd rebuild the **Launch Services Database**, using:

```
/S*/L*/F*/C*/F*/L*/S*/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```